# ColdFusion Application datasource Property not accessible in CFM Template

Tags: coldfusion

The following is running on a ColdFusion 2018 server (in the event this is a version-specific issue).

I'm setting the Application datasource property in the onApplicationStart() LifeCycle Handler, but the datasource property isn't accessible in a CFM Template.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with how the `this` Scope is handled inside the onApplicationStart() method, but I'm not certain. I tried setting the datasource property using `this.datasource` as well as `Application.datasource`, but it's not accessible in the CFM Template either way.

**Application.cfc**

```
// The usual App config stuff here... (omitted for brevity) 

// Instantiate Instance of Java System Object used to set System Env Vars
this.System = createObject("java", "java.lang.System");

// Include Config files
include "resources/config/AppSettings.cfm";
include "resources/config/onApplicationStart.cfm";
```

**AppSettings.cfm**

```
if (! isDefined(this.System.getProperty("DB_DSN_CREATED")))
{
    // Code to read values from .env file here ... (omitted for brevity) 

    // Set System Env Vars
    this.System.setProperty("DB_USER_NAME",     "DB USERNAME FROM .ENV FILE HERE");
    this.System.setProperty("DB_USER_PASSWORD", "DB PASSWORD FROM .ENV FILE HERE");
}
```

**onApplicationStart.cfm**

```
if (! isDefined(this.System.getProperty("DB_DSN_CREATED")))
{
    this.datasources = {MY_DSN = { PROPS FOR DB CONNECTION HERE }};

    // *** NOTE: This is the Property that isn't accessible in the CFM Template
    //           I also tried Application.datasource, but that didn't work either
    this.datasource = "MY_DSN";

    this.System.setProperty("DB_DSN_CREATED", true);
}
```

**db-test.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
    variables.appInstance = createObject('component', 'Application');

    variables.sql = "SQL STATEMENT HERE";
    variables.sqlParams = {};

    // *** NOTE: variables.appInstance.datasource below isn't accessible 
    //           I also tried Application.datasource but that didn't work either
    variables.sqlResult = queryExecute(variables.sql, variables.sqlParams, {datasource = variables.appInstance.datasource});

    writeDump(variables.sqlResult);
</cfscript>
```

Does anyone see what I'm missing? Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Looks more complicated than necessary.  My approach would be to set the datasource in the Application.cfc file, either outside any method or in an onApplicationStart method.  Also, when testing, I would have my db-test.cfm file in the same directory as Application.cfc which would take away the requirement to create an object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This actually works if I put all the code in the Application.cfc, but I wanted to use the LifeCycle Handlers -vs- having a large App.cfc, and also only execute the code onApplicationStart(). Do you happen to know if my problem has to do with the "this" or "Application' Scope when in the onApplicationStart() Handler?

Comment: Your snippet does not show where in the Application.cfc you are setting your variables.

Comment: You are correct, in the snippet I provided I did not set the vars in Application.cfc, I set them in onApplicationStart.cfm. I tried to bind them to "this" (ex: this.datasource) thinking that would reference the Application, and also tried to bind them directly to the Application Scope (Application.datasource), but neither worked from inside onApplicationStart.cfm. As mentioned, if I put all the code in Application.cfc it works, but it made the App.cfc fairly large and "cluttered", so I wanted to use multiple files to make the code more readable/maintainable.

Comment: TBH, this does seem unnecessarily complex. But ignoring that for a sec 1) What's the purpose of the `createObject()` call? Assuming there's an Application.cfc in the path, the server would have already executed it automatically long before `db-test.cfm` runs. 2) I'm pretty sure creating another instance of application manually (i.e. out of context) isn't going achieve the same effect as when CF does it automatically 3) Is there a specific reason for using java.lang.System? Modifying system properties can impact other applications on the JVM. Best to stick with the narrowest scope possible.

Comment: `.. assuming there's an Application.cfc in the path, the server would have already executed it automatically before db-test.cfm runs`  ... making point # 2 moot.

Comment: I do agree the createObject() is unnecessary (especially due to the feedback here). I had originally tried to access the datasource property using Application.datasource in db-test.cfm, but  it wasn't accessible. So, based on some search results, I tried to create an instance of the Application using createObject() to see if I could access the property, but that didn't work either. Based on all of the comments above, it seems my best bet is to put the code back in Application.cfc instead of using multiple files. As mentioned, the code does work in App.cfc, it just makes the file rather large.

Comment: I "resolved" this by putting the code in the Application.cfc as suggested above. I honestly don't like it, because the Datasource  is being created on every request (when the Application.cfc is "executed"). However, if I put the code in onApplicationStart(), even if the method is in Application.cfc, it doesn't work. For some reason which I don't understand, the "this" Scope in the onApplicationStart() method doesn't add the property to the Application Scope, so it's not accessible in the CFMs/CFCs that need the datasource property. Thanks for all your comments on this though, I appreciate it!

Comment: Thinking on this some more, I suspect you may be misunderstanding how the Application's `this` scope operates (: It's not persistent.  Your code actually does "work" - at least in the sense that the include successfully changes the `this.datasource` setting when invoked. However, since the Application.cfc gets instantiated on *every* request, that means its `this` scope gets recreated on every request. That effectively wipes out any changes you made in `OnApplicationStart`, making it *appear* the code doesn't work. Bottom line, the Application's `this` scope isn't intended to be used that way.

Comment: I figured I wasn't understanding the proper context of "this" in the Application.cfc. What you say makes sense, and now I know why this isn't working as expected. I was trying to figure out a way to only set the datasource once for the Application (programmatically), then have it apply to all requests. Thanks for coming back and clarifying for me!

Comment: Thank you for posting such a clear and well expressed question, with just the right amount of code! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking on this some more, I suspect you may be misunderstanding how an Application.cfc's `this` scope operates. Short answer:  `this` isn't persistent, like the `application` scope, because the component gets instantiated on every request

> *From [Defining the application and its event handlers in
> Application.cfc](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/designing-and-optimizing-a-coldfusion-application/defining-the-application-and-its-event-handlers-in-application-c.html)*
>
> When ColdFusion receives a request, it **instantiates** the
> Application CFC and runs the Application.cfc code ...

Your code actually *does* work. At least in the sense that the `include` successfully changes the value of `this.datasource` when invoked. However, since the Application.cfc gets instantiated anew on *every request*, the component's `this` scope also gets recreated. Essentially wiping out any previous changes made inside `OnApplicationStart()`. That's why it seems like the code never assigns a datasource value, when it actually does.

Bottom line, an Application.cfc's `this` scope isn't intended to be used that way.

---

#### Test Case

FWIW, you can see the behavior in action using the test files below. Just load `test.cfm` in a browser (at least twice) then check the logs. The output shows a value IS assigned to `this.datasource` the very first time test.cfm is requested from the application. However, that value disappears on the next http request because CF creates a new Application.cfc instance.

**Application.cfc**

```
component 
{
    this.name = "myApp_0001";

    function onApplicationStart(){
        writeLog("onApplicationStart()");
        writeLog(serializeJSON({"name": this.name, "datasource": this?.datasource?: "" }));
        include "onApplicationStart.cfm";
    }
    function onRequestStart( string targetPage ) {
        writeLog("onRequestStart()");
        writeLog(serializeJSON({"name": this.name, "datasource": this?.datasource?: "" }));
    }

}
```

**OnApplicationStart.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
    writeLog("onApplicationStart.cfm");
    writeLog(serializeJSON({"name": this.name, "datasource": this?.datasource?: "" }));
    
    writeLog("Assigning this.datasource");
    this.datasource = "MY_DSN";
    
    writeLog("Post Assign this.datasource");
    writeLog(serializeJSON({"name": this.name, "datasource": this?.datasource?: "" }));
</cfscript>
```

**test.cfm**

```
<h3>Test.cfm <cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput></h3>
```

**Results:**

```
Request #1 - this.Datasource gets assigned
[INFO ] ... - onApplicationStart()
[INFO ] ... - {""datasource"":"""",""name"":""myApp_0001""}
[INFO ] ... - onApplicationStart.cfm
[INFO ] ... - {""datasource"":"""",""name"":""myApp_0001""}
[INFO ] ... - Assigning this.datasource
[INFO ] ... - Post Assign this.datasource
[INFO ] ... - {""datasource"":""MY_DSN"",""name"":""myApp_0001""}
[INFO ] ... - onRequestStart()
[INFO ] ... - {""datasource"":""MY_DSN"",""name"":""myApp_0001""}

Request #2 - this.datasource is no longer assigned
[INFO ] ... - onRequestStart()
[INFO ] ... - {""datasource"":"""",""name"":""myApp_0001""}

Request #3 - this.datasource is no longer assigned
[INFO ] ... - onRequestStart()
[INFO ] ... - {""datasource"":"""",""name"":""myApp_0001""}
```